# Can I make a SQL SERVER Role to connect in BD only by a client? (program)

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2019

I was wondering if there is any possibility that an SQL user who logs in through Windows authentication can be configured either with a role or with specific user settings that allow them to connect and perform CRUD operations on a database, but prevent them from connecting to SSMS.

I know it might sound crazy, but I have tried revoking the permission to connect to SQL from the server, and granting permissions to a role on the desired database, but it still doesn't work. Here's the script I've been using:

```
 USE MASTER
CREATE USER [MyDom\myUser] FOR LOGIN [MyDom\myUser];

USE MASTER;
ALTER USER [MyDom\myUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;
ALTER ROLE [public] ADD MEMBER [MyDom\myUser];

GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [MyDom\myUser];

REVOKE CONNECT SQL TO [MyDom\myUser];

USE [myBD];
CREATE ROLE [myRole];
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [myRole];

ALTER USER [MyDom\myUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;
ALTER ROLE [myRole] ADD MEMBER [MyDom\myUser];
```

Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: SSMS is nothing special, if user can perform things, then he can do it through SSMS. Which actual problem are you trying to solve

Comment: @siggemannen My problem lies in the fact that application users have the database on the same PC, and if a user becomes curious and opens SSMS, and by chance logs in with SQL authentication... they will have access to the database and can execute scripts, 
which is dangerous. On my part, I requested simply removing SSMS from the PC since it is not necessary, but due to inconveniences with other individuals, it cannot be done. However, the security loophole must still be addressed, and that is why I'm posting this to see if it can be managed from SSMS itself.

Comment: You want them to be able to run SQL but not through SSMS?  Do you have an app or UI they are using to do this?  If so you can give the app the permissions you want them to have and have them log in but the app ID is what is connecting to the DB, so they wont be able to connect through SSMS because their Windows ID wont have access.

Comment: Sounds stupid to be honest. If you disable SSMS, they might start some other application etc. i think you'll need to remove their windows user rights and then use some other user if they really need to work with the server. Well, you can probably use some weird trigger that watches logins and kills users with wrong application Name, but please, don't, since some user will probably be legitimate. Better do nothing?

Comment: If the users are only ever granted execute permissions - then even if they connect using SSMS the only thing they can do is execute those procedures.  As soon as you grant them direct access to the tables - all bets are off.  It isn't only SSMS you need to worry about - Powershell, SQLCMD and any other scripting language could be used - or they could download DbVisualizer, Toad or any other database utility.

Comment: Thanks for your opinions and through research, I've come to the conclusion the SQL tools on the computers where programs are installed must have application-level restrictions, either through Active Directory roles or application rules. This is because it is nearly impossible to restrict SQL itself. Additionally, as mentioned before, there are vulnerabilities not only in SSMS but also in SQLcmd and PowerShell. I'dproposed this to the place where I'm facing this dilemma, but they were hesitant at first. However, it's important to implement these measures for better security